# simulate an HTTP request with curl

Tags: http, curl, unicode, httpie

I'm trying to debug an HTTP request that produces an error on our server. However, I'm struggling to reproduce the exact request somehow.

On my nginx logs, I see this entry which generated the error

`157.55.33.20 - - [22/Nov/2013:04:06:22 +0000] "GET /en/library/search?utf8=\xE2\x9C\x93&q=something HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"`

However, trying to use `curl` or `httpie` using the same string produces log entries like:

`GET /en/library/search?utf8=\x5CxE2\x5Cx9C\x5Cx93&q=something`

or

`GET /en/library/search?utf8=xE2x9Cx93&q=something`

or

`GET /en/library/search?utf8=%5CxE2%5Cx9C%5Cx93&q=something`

I just can't seem to reproduce the exact same request. I tried with various command-line parameters, but can't figure this one out.

Any suggestions on how to reproduce the exact same request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create HTTP requests with greater freedom with telnet. To start a connection, type this at the command line:

```
telnet www.example.com 80
```

(Here, 80 corresponds to the port number for HTTP requests). Once you're connected, you'll see a message like this:

```
Trying 12.34.56.78...
Connected to www.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

You can then type in your request, e.g.:

```
GET /en/library/search?utf8=\xE2\x9C\x93&q=something HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Finish with two carriage returns to mark the end of the header.

> **EDIT:** lcornea's suggestion is also worth considering. If your command line terminal
>   accepts UTF8 (type in `echo $LANG` to find out), then type (or paste) the character ✓
>   (check mark) instead of the three escaped characters. Or on a Windows Latin-1 terminal,
>   type in âœ“ instead.

Comment: Since the website is using SSL I used `openssl s_client` but I'm getting similar results as in my answer in the nginx log: `GET /en/library/search?utf8=\x5CxE2\x5Cx9C\x5Cx93&q=something`

Comment: The second suggestion did it though! `curl 'https://my.website.com/en/library/search?utf8=✓&q=something'` reproduced the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: like, use CLI telnet instead of cURL to verify Unicode in requests? For real? I'd say this is a bad joke, but sadly it doesn't seem so...

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as \xE2\x9C\x93 are actual UTF8 chars re-encoded by your server to be able to put them in the logs. Maybe look at what the chars actually are in UTF8 and put the chars in the URL.

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out. How to simulate the same request, hence my question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It helped @squeamish ossifrage to give the full answer.

Comment: @Yoav Aner I'm glad my answer helped you give the full response. Your response is very good work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\xYZ` use `%YZ` and it will be the same. For example replace `\xE2` to `%E2` in CURL request.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but the log shows `GET /en/library/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93`

Answer (score 0):

Have you try: curl -s -o /dev/null "http://yoursite.com/en/library/search?utf8=\xE2\x9C\x93&q=something" ?

Comment: I tried and it produced the same result as above `GET /en/library/search?utf8=\x5CxE2\x5Cx9C\x5Cx93`