# Rails 6.1 parameters encoding set to ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Prior to upgrading to Rails 6.1 we had an old code that was forcing all params to be UTF-8, adapted from here:
[Rails 2.3.9 Encoding of Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268778/rails-2-3-9-encoding-of-query-parameters)

Now Rails makes parameters frozen, so this code failed. We've read the docs and the internet and figured that Rails should encode params as UTF-8 by default, and this workaround is not needed anymore.
But no, all our parameters are now encoded as ASCII-8BIT.

We have `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in application.rb.
I even tried gems 'utf8-cleaner' and 'rack-utf8_sanitizer' - nothing helps, parameters are still have encoding ASCII-8BIT. Don't know if that helps but `request.body.read.encoding` is also ASCII-8BIT, but that should be expected, I think.

Is it's our code/config issue?

Comment: I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079365/parse-windows-1252-param-in-rails-action .